# GROUP BY HAVING COUNT CLAUSE on 5 Columns DB2

Tags: db2

I have 5 columns, I should check for the same account number more than once.

Table:

```
In  Out AccountNumber   Amount  Status
----------------------------------------
1   2   32345678        458.00  Accepted
12  7   12345678        958.00  Rejected
4   5   12345678        478.00  Rejected
6   1   21345678        408.00  Accepted
```

Desired Output: 
12  7   12345678        958.00  Rejected

This is my query:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, Amount, Status, Out, In
FROM FTM.Table
GROUP BY AccountNumber
HAVING COUNT (AccountNumber) > 1
```

Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s the result desired?

Comment: Desired result should be like below since account number is more than once:
Output
12  7   12345678        958.00  Rejected

Comment: Why should namely this row be returned, and not another row with the same account number?

Comment: It's actually doesn't matter, it can return any one of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select AccountNumber, Amount, Status, Out, In
From
(
SELECT AccountNumber, Amount, Status, Out, In
, rownumber() over (partition by AccountNumber) rn
, count(1) over (partition by AccountNumber) cnt
FROM FTM.Table
)
where cnt>1 and rn=1;
```

## Joining to another table

```
WITH TAB (ID, In, Out, AccountNumber, Amount, Status) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1,  1, 2, 32345678, 458.00, 'Accepted')
, (2, 12, 7, 12345678, 958.00, 'Rejected')
, (3,  4, 5, 12345678, 478.00, 'Rejected')
, (4,  6, 1, 21345678, 408.00, 'Accepted')
)
Select T1.AccountNumber, T1.Amount, T1.Status, T2.Out, T2.In 
From 
( 
SELECT AccountNumber, Amount, Status, Out, In, ID
, rownumber() over (partition by AccountNumber) rn
, count(1) over (partition by AccountNumber) cnt 
FROM TAB
) T1 
JOIN TAB T2 
ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
where T1.cnt>1 and T1.rn=1;
```

Comment: Brainstien, thanks a lot, I do see all the unique account number now, If I want to join a new table to it, should I do like below.
Select T1.AccountNumber, T1.Amount, T1.Status, T2.Out, T2.In
From
(
SELECT AccountNumber, Amount, Status, Out, In
, rownumber() over (partition by AccountNumber) rn
, count(1) over (partition by AccountNumber) cnt
FROM FTM.Table AS T1
JOIN FTM.Table AS T1
ON ID = ID
)
where cnt>1 and rn=1;

Comment: `Select T1.AccountNumber, T1.Amount, T1.Status, T2.Out, T2.In From ( SELECT AccountNumber, Amount, Status, Out, In , ID, rownumber() over (partition by AccountNumber) rn , count(1) over (partition by AccountNumber) cnt FROM FTM.Table) T1 JOIN TFM.Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID where T1.cnt>1 and T1.rn=1`

Comment: Thanks BrainStein. but this didn't work.It was giving me join error

Comment: @Chris What's the full error message of the "join error"? I've added an example of joining to another table. Run it **as is** to check. If it doesn't work, then what's your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, Your join condition `T2.ID = T1.ID` is not correct as there is no such `T1.ID`.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai There **is** such a column in the T1 subselect: "..., In , **ID**, rownumber(...".

Comment: Ok. Got it. My bad.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, My bad, It worked as expected. There was a syntax error in query, I just corrected that. Thanks a lot Mark, appreciate it.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @Chris It would be good enough, if you marked the question as answered then.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for wording. It’s called here as “accepted”, not “answered”. This may be done not changing the topic header, but setting the corresponding check box probably.